# Using Partitioner along with RateLimit in Greenpipes/Masstransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to combine Partitioner and RateLimiter filters in Greenpipes. The code below that I have now doesn't work as expected:

```
cfg.UseDispatch(new RequestConverterFactory(), d =>
{
    d.Handle<Request<RenderBasemapRequest>>(h =>
    {
        h.UsePartitioner(1,
            context => context.Request.ServiceProvider.GetService<IIdentityService>().CurrentIdentityId
            ); // 1 user can request only for 1 screenshot in parallel.
        h.UseRateLimit(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)); // 5 requests per user per minute
        h.UseHandler<RenderBasemapRequest, Stream>();
    });
});
```

I want to limit user to make only 5 requests per minute max. But UseRateLimit sets up it globally regardless if there's partition filter above, so I get 5 requests per minute for all users at once. Is it possible to achieve what I want with Greenpipes filters? Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the partitioner doesn't create a unique partition for each user. Basically, with a partition count of one, you've created a concurrency limit of, well, one.

It doesn't create a partition for every key, it uses the key to calculate a hash to spread the load across the available partitions.

Second, it should use a property of the message. The fact you're accessing the container to get a service provider and call some method -- yeah, that's a bit beyond what you should be doing at that stage of the pipeline. Could become a bottleneck, just be aware.

The rate limit works, but it should be prior to the partitioner, and doesn't have the ability to discern or limit per client. That is coming in Conductor, but it isn't ready yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply. Regarding the container, the question is not related to MassTransit, actually. I'm trying to enable the power of Greenpipes in API project after successful MT adoption. But the tag Greenpipes doesn't exist on SO and I cannot create it. Could you please share a link on github branch where you implement Conductor? Maybe I can learn something from it.